# Setting up Cron Job through URL involving authentication token

Tags: php, curl, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have script which first authenticates an odesk user and returns access tokens and then executes some code. After i get authenticated it redirects me to the same page say http://somewebsite.com/odesk/index.php and starts to write a file.

When i call the url mannualy, it starts to write which means there's no problem with the script. I now added the script to cronjob on hosting environment and executed it but it seems to have no effect on files.
CURL is available so the command i gave to cronjob:

```
curl http://www.somewebsite.com/odesk/index.php
```

I did everything to make it run but with no success.
What am i missing?

Comment: did you check if curl's in the path of the shell cron is using? is curl even installed on the server?

Comment: Yes, curl is installed on the server.

Comment: I believe its something related to the authentication that might be missing on server.

Comment: If you have SSH access, then run the cron command from SSH command line. You can echo the variable values in the PHP scripts for debugging which will be shown on command line